# Best practices to structure jquery and javascript (using objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, code-organization

I am building a javascript/jquery intensive site and even by the time I am in my second html page I already have a very long js file.

My page is filled with HTML elements (buttons, checkboxes, draggable/droppable lists etc etc). And all the interaction listeners and handlers are all inside a single monolithic wrapper of `$(document).ready(...`

I was thinking of making separate JS files for separate "group" of actions,but I am not sure if that is a good idea considering the multiple http fetch operations that will be required.

From a structuring perspective, I wanted to try a more object-oriented approach. However I am not very sure about it as I am not really a front-end/JS programmer. I have seen code where people like their whole JS required for their app as an object with event handler registration and so on. Will this be just redundant if I am already using jQuery? Are there any followed/establish practices for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can organize your code as Functions, parts of your code.

You interact with your functions inside your unique $(document).ready
so you can place all your other functions in other files.

Like in draggble.js, you have your draggle functions etcs.. you can even do it in a OOP JS style even if think it is not the best way to do that, because of jQuery.

that's one way to do it, you have million ways.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, many ways to achieve this.
I use [commonjs](http://www.commonjs.org/) and make every piece of code a module. You can require or import every module and have a cleaner dev project. Then you package them as one file 'a la' [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/docs/commonjs.html) or as you configure it with any build-tool or [NPM](https://medium.com/@dabit3/introduction-to-using-npm-as-a-build-tool-b41076f488b0).